# How to use google latitude apis for iphone application?

Tags: iphone, location, google-api, google-latitude

I want to make google latitude type application for iphone.For that i have looked at google  latitude api.for that
http://code.google.com/apis/latitude/v1/using_rest.html#auth.i have looked at this api documentation.but it requires domain name registration for application and it is for web applications.
Can anyone tell this if i can use and develope this application for iphone.any tutorials or sample code or example for that?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look at this tutorial instead....

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/tutorial-iphone.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in case anyone is looking for it later, you want to look at the documentation for oauth for installed applications:
http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html#installed or web server applications:
http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html#webserver

Neither of those should require a domain